# Contar registros do banco de dados sem repetir

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela que possui vários registros com a mesma informação, exemplo:

```
id |  nome      |  profissao
1     Carlos       Pedreiro
2     Jean         Garçon
3     Victor       Pedreiro
4     Ana Paula    Secretaria
5     Paula        Secretaria
6     Karina       Balconista
```

O que eu preciso contar é a quantidade de profissão mas sem que repita, no exemplo que eu dei, possui 6 registros, mas só possui 4 profissões diferentes, é isso que preciso contar, eu não sei como fazer para que conte mas sem repetir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
   t.profissao,
   COUNT(t.profissao) as total
FROM
   tabela t
GROUP BY
   t.profissao
```

No `SELECT` coloque `COUNT(t.profissao)`, agrupando pelo mesmo campo, ou seja, `GROUP BY t.profissao`. Dessa forma ele irá retornar a quantidade de repetições de cada profissão, e para saber qual profissão pertence a quantidade mostrada, basta adicionar o campo `profissao`, como mostrado na `query` acima.

O resultado da query seria mais ou menos esse:

```
total     |  profissao
2            Pedreiro
1            Garçon
2            Secretaria
1            Balconista
```

Comment: Depois disso é só dar um rowCount()?

Comment: Da forma que está o `SELECT`, ele irá retorna uma consulta com dois campos. Um chamado `profissao` com o nome da profissao e outro campo chamado `total`, mostrando a quantidade do mesmo.

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigado!